# Asp.Net : Web service throws "Thread was being aborted"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service that I call via ajax that requires the user to be logged in.  in each method I want to check if the user is logged in and send a 403 code if they are not, however when I call a `Response.End()` I get the error "Thread was being aborted".  What should I call instead?

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public string MyMethod()
{
    if(!userIsLoggedIn)
    {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
    /* Do stuff that should not execute unless the user is logged in... */
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a `WebMethod`, the easiest method is to just return nothing.  This would be equivalent behavior to ending the response for an ajax request:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public string MyMethod()
{
    if(!userIsLoggedIn)
    {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will I throw an error if I return null on a non nullable type?

Comment: @Master - It shouldn't let you compile that, but you can throw `default(typeHere)` to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

From the [MS Support issue page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/):

> If you use the Response.End,
>   Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer
>   method, a ThreadAbortException
>   exception occurs. You can use a
>   try-catch statement to catch this
>   exception.
>
> This behavior is by design.
>
> To work around this problem, use one
>   of the following methods:
>
> 1. For Response.End, call the
>      HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest
>      method instead of Response.End to
>      bypass the code execution to the
>      Application_EndRequest event.